20 GB of "Other" files?
I have a Samsung Galaxy S9+ with 64 GB.
I deleted almost every app (including WhatsApp). At this moment, my archive says that there are 19.57 GB of files in a group named "Other" (or "others", I don't know because the name is in Italian and the name is "Altro")

I downloaded cleaning apps
Searched for hidden files
Partitioned caches
Connected the phone to the computer
Searched for videos on YouTube but they all advertise the same app which doesn't work

But I can't delete these files at all (I honestly would like to avoid getting to the point of having to reset the phone)
But 19.57 GB of space occupied by unknown things out of a maximum of 64 GB seems excessive to me, taking into account that it tells me there are:

11.63 GB of "System".
8.57 GB of "Application" I can not uninstall (in the group "Application", it says that I have 11.30 GB of application, but currently looking at the app store, I actually only have 2.72 GB of apps installed)

(11.63 + 19.57 + 8.57) / 64 = 62.14%
I have more than 60% of the storage memory occupied by files that are not mine, and since I cannot delete system applications, I would like to at least be able to delete the "other" group.
Could someone please help me? I've been trying to figure this out for months.

What cleaning apps have you tried and how have you tried to delete files.  Why do you have Italian named folder/files on your phone?

Possible dupe: How disk space is used on Android device?

This question is similar to: How disk space is used on Android device?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@RohitGupta Because I'm italian. The app is "Device Storage Analitics". This app can see only the file I can see too, but there are other 19.57 GB of file that I can not see and (and the app can't see either) of the "other" group

From the adb shell, try du -h /data/local/tmp. That directory is used for temporary files and is normally empty, but stuff can get left there.
